# how to make "border-image" property rounded?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am going to redesign the Instagram website for training and there was a problem, how should I make the story part of the Instagram website? it has rounded border with gradiant.

we know that we should use `border-image` property to have a gradiant border, but how should we round it just like the Instagram website ?

[[image]]

I searched for the methods but it did not work. I will appreciate any help with that.